# Is this 开会 only means "hold a meeting" of 今天有点儿冷,开会儿暖气吧。

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 今天有点儿冷,开会儿暖气吧。

I guess that 开会 here might have a meaning of  "turn on a switch" or kind of like that.

But as I looked up several dictionaries then I was only able to find a definition "to hold/attend a meeting".

And about 暖气, I've only been able to find out that this term can only be as noun.

Is there some misprint exists in the original sentence?

Comment: [开](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%96%8B#Chinese) (to turn on) [会儿](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83%E5%85%92#Chinese) (for a while)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've parsed it incorrectly. Here 开 + 会儿 are separate words.

- [开](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%BC%80) = to turn on
- [会儿](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%B8%80%E4%BC%9A%E5%84%BF) = for a bit / for a moment

---

If you put the sentence into a [machine translation](https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E4%BB%8A%E5%A4%A9%E6%9C%89%E7%82%B9%E5%84%BF%E5%86%B7%2C%E5%BC%80%E4%BC%9A%E5%84%BF%E6%9A%96%E6%B0%94%E5%90%A7%E3%80%82&op=translate) you'd get something like:

> It's a bit cold today, let's turn on the heating for a while.

Which would give you a good idea of what the original meant.

Answer (score 2):

开***会儿***暖气 = 开***一会儿***暖气 = Turn on the heater for a while.

In colloquial language, ***一*** is often omitted in ***一会儿***. It is not very often used in the literature.